# how to match a word from string in jolt transformation

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

I have start writing a jolt transformation, and getting challenge to match the word from the object value.

input JSON :

```
{
  "application" : "android",
  "issue" : "FoundCriticalBug",
}
```

now if the value in key `"issue"` is *critical* then print `bug is "critical"` else the value may comes like `"FoundNetworkBug"` or `"FoundNoBug"`

expected output :

```
{
  "application" : "android",
  "issue" : "FoundCriticalBug",
  "bug" : "critical"
}
```

There would be a `if-else` condition applied but i didn't went further. do suggest.

Comment: Do you mean whether the value of the `issue` attribute _contains_ the substring **critical** ?

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan
Yes...the value may comes like 'FoundCriticalBug'/'FoundNetworkBug'/'FoundNoBug'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a hash symbol(`#`) for the case only when the `issue` is equal to

`FoundCriticalBug`(considering *the three presented fixed values*) in order to generate a line

`"bug" : "critical"` representing a new attribute as follows

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&",
      "issue": {
        "FoundCriticalBug": {
          "@1": "&2",
          "#critical": "bug"
        },
        "*": {
          "@1": "&2"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```